# javascript code prevents typing except special characters

Tags: javascript

I was putting together some simple javascript to prevent characters being input in my form.  I got to this stage where I was able to prevent all typing, and noticed that it prevents all characters **except** special ones, like `å`´`ˆ`ø`¨

which I can enter on my mac using: [Option]+`+[Letter key]

How can I prevent these being entered?

HTML:

```
<form>
  <input name="myinput"></input>
</form>
```

JS:

```
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 return false; 
});
```

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/6qty7dgr/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use `<input disabled>`?

Comment: @LionelRowe I want to build this up to allow only certain characters

Comment: Don't bother? Allow the typing, let people input whatever nonsense they want. Then reject it [when you _validate_ the form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) prior to allowing it to submit. And then, because you're practicing safe programming, you do the same validation at the server, because people can circumvent validation if they know enough JS to try to force their way through.

Comment: it's really imprecise as a question, there are thousands of utf8 characters, and they are all likely to be entered (or even copied) in a text type imput, rather to list those you refuse, rather do it list the ones you accepted, then use a regex. but I think this question has already been asked here and you haven't researched it !

Comment: @MisterJojo what is imprecise?  I'm simply asking how to prevent these specific special characters being input on the form fields?  The event listener doesn't seem to catch them

Comment: Is it only keystrokes? so you accept these only 2 characters if they arrive by the copy paste of one or more words that can contain one or more times one of these  2 characters?

Comment: none of those queries are relevant to my actual question.  I'm asking why the javascript event handler isn't working in this case - I'm not asking for help with my use-case

Comment: This is a known madness with keyboard events, unfortunately, you need to have workarounds. Read JavaScript Madness: Keyboard :Eventshttps://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: Note that your current code won't handle pasted content either, nor inputs from STT.

Answer (score 3):

This is not working because these keystrokes actually start a [composition event](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#events-compositionevents), i.e the full input has not yet been processed by the IME and you have "half-a-character". So calling `preventDefault()` on the keydown event here won't prevent the typing of this half character and the browser will insert it in the input anyway.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('compositionstart', function (e) {
  console.log("composition start fired");
  e.preventDefault(); // should have worked per specs, but doesn't...
});
```

```html
  <input name="myinput"></input>
```

By specs, you should have been able to prevent this by calling `preventDefault()` on the [`compositionstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/compositionstart_event) event that does fire. However, no browser actually seems to support cancelling this event and it seems that for [technical reasons](https://crbug.com/706672) they won't support it ever. However they should support cancelling the [`beforeinput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/beforeinput_event) event, but as of today only Safari does support cancelling it when it comes from a composition event...

Answer (score 1):

> *"I was putting together some simple javascript to **prevent characters being input in my form**."*
> *"How can I prevent these being entered?"*

<sup>Emphasis added by me</sup>

Avoid keyboard events if you are using a form control. Form events usually work better since there is very little variation when interpreting the value of an input as opposed to keyboard events.

In the example below, the `<input>` listens for the "input" event. As the user types into the `<input>`, the `.value` property is being filtered by the following Regexp:

```
const rgx = new RegExp(/([å´ˆø`¨])*/, 'g');
```

- `(`...`)`- Capture group: matched characters that are extracted.
- `*`----- Quantifier: zero or more matches.
- `[`...`]`- Class: a literal character. `-`, `\`, `]`, and `^` must be escaped by prefixing `\` to it.

``` å´ˆø``¨ ``` are instantly replaced with a zero-space `""`.

***Details are commented in example below***

```js
// Bind input tag to the input event
document.forms[0].elements.filter.oninput = dataFilter;

// Pass the Event Object
function dataFilter(e) {
  // Delegate to input tag only
  if (this.name == 'filter') {
    /*
    This matches 
    å´ˆø`¨
    */
    const rgx = new RegExp(/([å´ˆø`¨])*/, 'g');
    // Replace everything in rgx
    const filtered = this.value.replace(rgx, '');
    // Assign filtered string as value
    this.value = filtered;
  }
  // Prevent input from rendering everything
  e.preventDefault();
};
```

```html
<form>
  <input name='filter'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: The onkeypress event is not fired for all keys (e.g. ALT, CTRL, SHIFT, ESC) in all browsers. To detect only whether the user has pressed a key, use the onkeydown event instead, because it works for all keys.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp

Comment: changing the event to `'keydown'` still doesn't prevent these characters being entered in the Fiddle